# Word: an inability to understand a spoken language

Tags: single-word-requests

*Illiterate* is used to describe someone who cannot read. 
I am looking for a word to describe someone who cannot understand a spoken language.

> David was [unable to understand French] {People are speaking french around him}
>
> Jean's friends were laughing about a joke, but David was [unable to understand French] and didn't know what they were laughing about

Not-fluent is the obvious compound, but it is rather inelegant.

Comment: Jean's friends were laughing about a joke, but David ne parlait pas français. It's a *pejorative* in English when applied to humans, but [dumb](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/dumb) would seem to fit.

Comment: There are also persons who have what is called a "reading knowledge" of a foreign tongue, meaning they can read texts composed/encoded in that language but cannot manage either to produce or to follow conversation in it. This is especially the case with languages that have evolved far from the phonetic ideal, where written forms may suggest cognates that the spoken forms do not.

Comment: You could also say "david is slow."

Comment: @vickyace he's not dumb or slow, he just doesn't speak french!

Comment: *David, being a non-speaker,* should cut it. From the context one understands that he is not aphasic, he just doesn't speak French.

Comment: "A foreigner." Illiterate is (usually) used to describe someone who cannot read *their own language*. I don't have high hopes for finding *illiterate*'s counterpart in your context.

Comment: If the language in question is French then saying David is a "non-Francophone" covers it; it specifically means someone who does not speak or understand spoken French.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have two more proposals which come close to what you're looking for:

- A **monoglot** is someone who only speaks one language.
- An **anglophobe** is someone who is afraid of English. (This is a neologism)

Comment: I don't see how the second example applies here. Being unable to speak French doesn't make you afraid of English.

Comment: @KillingTime: Completely correct. As I said, it looks like there is no answer that fit precisely.

Comment: Of course, for French it would be francophobe, not anglophobe.

Comment: monolingual seems like the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

David was not Francophone!

This reply is from a "Hispanophone" who spent 40 minutes searching for the word "árabohablante" (Arabophone?) on the internet in 2021.

Perhaps this can help someone else in the future :)
Godspeed to you!

@fev: thank you for your comment. Following your suggestion, here is what the Oxford English Dictionary says about the word Francophone:

Origin: Formed within English, by compounding; modelled on a French lexical item.

Etymology: < Franco- comb. form + -phone comb. form, after French francophone, adjective (1880) and noun (1894).

Forms:  also with capital initial.

Meanings:

A) Noun → A French-speaking person. Example: "The study employs the terms anglophones, francophones and ‘others’ to denote respectively those who speak English, French or another language in their homes." (1969. Daily Colonist. (Victoria, Brit. Columbia). 5 July 5/1)

B) Adjective → French-speaking. Example: "The new poet laureate of Canada is Pauline Michel. Every report of her appointment identifies her as the first francophone writer to hold the post." (Times Lit. Suppl. 26 Nov. 16/2)

@KillingTime. I understand your point. However, this reply is only an alternative that may be useful to some :) Cheers!

Comment: Hello, and welcome to the EL&U. Your answer could be improved by providing references. See [tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: I think the question is after a more general term for not understanding a spoken language.

Comment: Wouldn't "not a Francophone" simply IMPLY that he does not understand the written word, too? I think that if you want to convey the idea that somebody can only understand the written words of a language but not speak it (or not speak it well), you cannot simply express that with a single word.

Answer (score 1):

How about [auditory aphasia or acoustic aphasia](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/auditory%20aphasia). It doesn't mean that he can't understand a language due to brain damage or hearing loss but there are other unknown reasons.

[Here](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/auditory-aphasia) is another link.

Comment: no, he doesn't have brain damage! He just doesn't speak French! I've edited the question to make it clear.

Comment: @socrates Didn't you understand what I typed? It says that he is not necessarily brain damaged but there are other "UNKNOWN REASONS."

Comment: @socrates Do you get it?

Comment: sorry, I misread your question.

Answer (score 0):

We would simply say

> David is a foreigner.

Illiterate is usually used to describe someone who cannot read their own language; not one that is *foreign* to them.

**foreign**, adjective –[Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=foreign%20definition&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)

> of, from, in, or characteristic of a country or language other than one's own.
>   "a foreign language"

Comment: But David could be a foreigner, yet understand French perfectly well.  Even, as with French-Canadians, have it as his native tongue.

Comment: Does 'foreigner' apply to someone from another country that speaks the same language? Eg, an Australian visiting England?

Comment: This answer is just wrong

Answer (score -2):

Benighted means unenlighted, so maybe you could use that, as in, "David is benighted in French", or something. Hope this helps, and if not, well, I tried.

Comment: This is less clear than "David doesn't understand (spoken) French".